# How you can control the size of a log file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We normally append in the log file and its obviously neccessary but after a particular file size is achived i want all the previous log to be deleted and new log should create. How this is possible?

Apart from using log4j. I am more interested if we could have any way from `FileHandler`.

Comment: You want to use FileHandler? Well... just do. Its api doc explains how. What problem do you have?

Comment: @downvoter... I guess you should also explain me why a downvote... this is a rule of community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log4J has a [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html). Java logging has [`FileHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html), which offers similar functionality. Other logging frameworks might have the same functionality. Check the documentation for your logging framework to know if it exists or not.

Comment: yes I have been going to this FileHandler doc...Before this answer i was not sure about how it gonna work but i guess we have enough material on filehandler. thanks for the help..Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you use log4j there are options that provide all of this functionality.

Comment: Don't shout. Instead, tell us what you would like to use. We don't have any crystal ball.

Comment: @JB Nizet hey man... its nothing about shouting... just expressing my view to the answer... thats it... i know how to respect the people who answers to my questions...you can see any questions i have asked previously...

Comment: Writing in all caps is considered as shouting. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette and http://www.kassj.com/netiquette/netiquette.html#1

Comment: @JB no shouting any more deleted the comment but that was not intentional... just my caps button was on. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

use log4j and `maxFileSize`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link , check fileappenders section for log4j, there it given clearly.

> [File Appenders](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.doc/rm_help/admin/configure_rm_logging.htm)